# Движение объекта QGraphicsRectItem при зажатой кнопке мыши

Tags: c++, qt

На `QGraphicsScene` расположен квадрат объекта класса унаследованного от `QGraphicsRectItem`. Пытаюсь сделать так, чтобы квадрат **постоянно** перемещался на 10 пикселей вправо, когда по нему нажимают левой кнопкой мыши или по экрану смартфона(android).
Основная проблема у меня с телефоном. У меня получается "велосипед". Я пытался решить проблему через сигналы и слоты. 
Ввел переменную `bool move` и опрашивал её каждые 60 секунд, если значение равно true, то перемещал квадрат. Проблема в том, что на android функция hoverLeaveEvent срабатывает только когда нажмешь по экрану, где не расположен мой объект.

```
class MoveButton:public QObject, public QGraphicsRectItem{
   Q_OBJECT

public:

MoveButton(QGraphicsItem* parent=NULL)
{
    setRect(0,0,200,200);
}


// (events)
void mousePressEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent *event) // работает только при первом нажатии
{
    setPos(x()+10, y());
}

void hoverEnterEvent(QGraphicsSceneHoverEvent *event);
void hoverLeaveEvent(QGraphicsSceneHoverEvent *event);
};
```

Как это исправить?

Answer (score 2):

Если отображаете с помощью `QGraphicsView`, то можно попробовать следующее:

установите фильтр событий

`yourGraphicsView->viewport()->installEventFilter(yourEventHandler);`

затем у `yourEventHandler` переопределите функцию

```
eventFilter(QObject* obj, QEvent* ev)
{
  if (obj == yourGrahicsView->viewport() &&
      ev->type() == QEvent::MouseButtonPress) {
    QPoint pos = static_cast<QMouseEvent*>(ev)->pos();
    QList<QGrahicsItems*> items = yourGraphicsView->items(pos);
    if (items.contains(yourGraphicsItem)) {
      /*Здесь ваш код*/
    }
  }
}
```